# t-test through all combinations of all factors all levels

Tags: r

I have a dataframe with the following structure:

```
> str(data_l)
'data.frame':   800 obs. of  5 variables:
 $ Participant: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 ...
 $ Temperature: Factor w/ 4 levels "35","37","39",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Region     : Factor w/ 5 levels "Eyes","Front",..: 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 3 ...
 $ Time       : Factor w/ 5 levels "0","15","30",..: 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ Rating     : num  5 5 5 4 5 5 5 5 5 5 ...
```

I want to run one-sample t-test for each combination of all factors all levels, for a total of 4*5*5 = 100 t-tests, with Rating as dependent variables, or `y`.

I am stuck at looping through the combinations, and performing t-test at each combo.

I tried splitting the dataframe by the factors, then `lapply` `t.test()` through the list, but to no avail.

Does anyone have a better approach? Cheers!

**Edit**

My ultimate intention is to calculate confidence interval for arrays in all factors all levels. For instance, I was able to do this:

```
subset1 <- data_l$Rating[data_l$Temperature == 35 & data_l$Region == "Front" & data_l$Time == 0]
```

Then,

```
t.test(subset1)$conf.int
```

But the problem is I will have to do this 100 times.

**Edit 2**

I am recreating the dataframe.

```
Temperature <- rep(seq(35, 41, 2), 10)
Region <- rep(c("Front", "Back", "Eyes", "Left", "Right"), 8)
Time <- rep(seq(0, 60, 15), 8)
Rating <- sample(1:5, 40, replace = TRUE)
data_l <- data.frame(Region = factor(Region), Temperature = factor(Temperature), Time = factor(Time), Rating = as.numeric(Rating))
```

Comment: Can you demonstrate a 3-way t-test?

Comment: As stated in the question, I wanted to perform one-sample t-test for each combination of factor levels. Not 3-way t-test, and that test doesn't exist.

Comment: What is the null hypothesis? That the mean value of Rating is 0? If rating is an ordinal variable with a limited number of values, the t-test would be inappropriate. With a sample size of 800 distributed over 100 tests you have about 8 values per test. Once you use `p-adjust` to correct for multiple comparisons you are likely to have 0 significant values. If you want to proceed anyway, the function expand.grid(1:4, 1:5, 1:5) will give you all of the combinations.

Comment: I'm confident that the test doesn't exist, that's why I asked. Now that you've mentioned that number ... there are 100 three-way combinations, but you cannot do 100 tests to get all two-way combinations. Let's take the first level of each factor, so you have three. You first do a t-test on the first from temp and region; then the first from temp and time; then the first from region and time. So three tests. Now, take your `4*5*5=100` and triple that, because that's how many two-way tests you have three 100 three-way combinations.

Comment: @dcarlson, I understand that, my ultimate goal is to obtain conf.int from the t-tests. I also tried expand.grid but just not sure how to include that in my t.test statement. Can you help?

Comment: You cannot just pass it to `t.test` and assume that the function is going to know what you need. You're going to have to manage the tests yourself. Can you walk your way through one such test? Do a manual filter of the data for *just* the levels you want for *one* t-test and perform that test ... and then we can likely help you complete the expansion you say you need.

Comment: Provide sample data if you want an example of how to do the analysis. 15-25 rows of the data set using `dput()` should be enough. Or just `subset()` to pull out the Ratings for each combination and run `t.test` on that.

Comment: @r2evans I have added the edit. Hope this clears the confusion.

Comment: You did not provide data. Since `Time` and `Temperature` are factors and not numeric values, I am surprised that your code actually worked.

Comment: Without actual data the best advice I can provide is `x <- expand.grid(levels(data_1$Temperature), levels(data_1$Region), levels(data_1$Time))` and then use `x` with a loop to create each of the 100 tests.

Comment: @dcarlson, dataframe recreated in Edit 2 above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two things.

1. Can this be done? Certainly. Should it? Many of your combinations may have insufficient data to find a reasonable confidence interval. While your data sample is certainly reduced and simplified, I don't have assurances that there will be sufficient fillingness of your factor combinations.

   ```r
   table(sapply(split(data_l$Rating, data_l[,c("Temperature","Region","Time")]), length))
   #  0  2 
   # 80 20
   ```

   (There are 80 "empty" combinations of your factor levels.)
2. Let's try this:

   ```r
   outs <- aggregate(data_l$Rating, data_l[,c("Temperature","Region","Time")],
                     function(x) if (length(unique(x)) > 1) t.test(x)$conf.int else c(NA, NA))
   nrow(outs)
   # [1] 20
   head(outs)
   #   Temperature Region Time        x.1        x.2
   # 1          35  Front    0         NA         NA
   # 2          37  Front    0  -9.706205  15.706205
   # 3          39  Front    0  -2.853102   9.853102
   # 4          41  Front    0 -15.559307  22.559307
   # 5          35   Back   15 -15.559307  22.559307
   # 6          37   Back   15  -4.853102   7.853102
   ```

   Realize that this is not five columns; the fourth is really a matrix embedded in a frame column:

   ```r
   head(outs$x)
   #            [,1]      [,2]
   # [1,]         NA        NA
   # [2,]  -9.706205 15.706205
   # [3,]  -2.853102  9.853102
   # [4,] -15.559307 22.559307
   # [5,] -15.559307 22.559307
   # [6,]  -4.853102  7.853102
   ```

   It's easy enough to extract:

   ```r
   outs$conf1 <- outs$x[,1]
   outs$conf2 <- outs$x[,2]
   outs$x <- NULL
   head(outs)
   #   Temperature Region Time      conf1     conf2
   # 1          35  Front    0         NA        NA
   # 2          37  Front    0  -9.706205 15.706205
   # 3          39  Front    0  -2.853102  9.853102
   # 4          41  Front    0 -15.559307 22.559307
   # 5          35   Back   15 -15.559307 22.559307
   # 6          37   Back   15  -4.853102  7.853102
   ```

   (If you're wondering why I have a conditional on `length(unique(x)) > 1`, then see what happens without it:

   ```r
   aggregate(data_l$Rating, data_l[,c("Temperature","Region","Time")],
             function(x) t.test(x)$conf.int)
   # Error in t.test.default(x) : data are essentially constant
   ```

   This is because there are combinations with empty data. You'll likely see something similar with not-empty but still invariant data.)

Answer (score 0):

> I am stuck at looping through the combinations, and performing t-test
>   at each combo.

I'm not sure if this is what you wanted.

```
N <- 800
df <- data.frame(Participant=1:N,
                 Temperature=gl(4,200),
                 Region=sample(1:5, 800, TRUE),
                 Time=sample(1:5, 800, TRUE),
                 Rating=sample(1:5, 800, TRUE))
head(df)

t_test <- function(data, y, x){
  x <- eval(substitute(x), data)
  y <- eval(substitute(y), data)

  comb <- combn(levels(x), m=2)  # this gives all pair-wise combinations
  n <- dim(comb)[2]
  t <- vector(n, mode="list")

  for(i in 1:n){
    xlevs <- comb[,i]
    DATA <- subset(data, subset=x %in% xlevs)
    x2 <- factor(x, levels=xlevs)
    tt <- t.test(y~x2, data=DATA)
    t[[i]] <- tt
    names(t)[i] <- toString(xlevs)
  }
  t
}

T.test <- t_test(df, Rating, Temperature)
```

---

```
T.test[1]
$`1, 2`

    Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  y by x2
t = -1.0271, df = 396.87, p-value = 0.305
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -0.4079762  0.1279762
sample estimates:
mean in group 1 mean in group 2 
           2.85            2.99
```